# Date casting: Error when inserting but not when selecting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote the following query to convert 3 varchar columns into 1 datetime column:

```
select 
    MYKEY, 
    CAST(
            CAST(YEAR AS VARCHAR(4)) +
            RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
            RIGHT('0' + CAST(DAY AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) as DATETIME) as AD_BORN
    from SOURCE
    where YEAR IS NOT NULL AND MONTH IS NOT NULL AND DAY IS NOT NULL AND YEAR<>''
```

It works and gives me the list of expected dates.
Nevertheless, when I try to insert its results into a new table I get an error:

> sql server conversion failed when converting date and/or time from
>   character string

This is my statement:

```
select 
    MYKEY, 
    CAST(
            CAST(YEAR AS VARCHAR(4)) +
            RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
            RIGHT('0' + CAST(DAY AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) as DATETIME) as AD_BORN
    into MY_DATES
    from SOURCE
    where YEAR IS NOT NULL AND MONTH IS NOT NULL AND DAY IS NOT NULL AND YEAR<>''
```

MY_DATES does not exist before this query. YEAR, MONT and DAY in SOURCE are varchar (4, 2 and 2 respectively). They may contain null values.

What's wrong with that?

Comment: How could we know without the datatypes of the tables? Can you  post the ddl of both tables and a few rows of sample data?

Comment: MY_DATES does not exist before this query. YEAR, MONT and DAY in SOURCE are varchar (4, 2 and 2 respectively). They may contain null values.

Comment: Create the string (e.g. `20120515`) without the cast and then use [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) in your where clause to see if any are not valid dates.

Answer (score 0):

No need to Pad your strings. If 2012+ use `try_convert()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Year] varchar(50),[Month] varchar(50),[Day] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (2018,1,25)
,(2018,5,55) -- Bogus Date

Select *
      ,AsDate = try_convert(date,[Month]+'/'+[Day]+'/'+[Year])
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Year    Month   Day AsDate
2018    1   25  2018-01-25
2018    5   55  NULL        -- Bogus Date
```